# Quick Look keeps popping up

Tags: macos, finder, desktop, quicklook

I use the <kbd>spacebar</kbd> to preview some files with Quick Look and when I'm done with it I close the preview window.

Sometimes when I change desktops the preview window will pop up again (empty) and when I try to close it, it will put me back on the desktop where I previewed an item.

This keeps occurring and I have no way of getting rid of it... Any solutions?
I'm using a OS X 10.9.3

Answer (score 1):

It's irritating, for sure - best workaround I've found is to relaunch the Finder...

Option Right-click the Finder icon in the Dock & you see an extra item at the bottom of the menu - Relaunch

[image]